# help with query - update from 2 tables

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

i have 2 tables

```
table1: num,X,Y

table2: num,X,Y
```

i need to update X and Y in table1 where table1.num = table2.num

how to do it ?

i need it in Oracle query (i think that in sql server it will work too)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FOR oracle:

```
 UPDATE table1 t1
 SET (x,Y) = (SELECT x, y from table2
             WHERE t1.num = t2.num)
```

FOR mssql:

```
 UPDATE t1
 SET x = t2.x,
     y = t2.y
 FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
 WHERE t1.num = t2.num
```